# Как сохранить контекст, передаваемый в статический метод в нестатическую переменную?

Tags: java, android, static, context

У некоего SDK есть статичный метод `initialize(Context context)`. Как мне сохранить контекст в нестатическую переменную? Если я делаю так, то студия ругается на `memory leak`.

```
public class SomeSDK {
    public static Context mContext;

    public static void initialize(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }
}
```

Контекст будет использоваться во всем SDK

Comment: Не сочтите за тавтологию, но не хватает контекста. Непонятно для чего вам это делать, как вы пробовали это делать и что именно не получилось. Думаю, кусок кода тут был бы не лишним.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, обновил вопрос

Comment: Что такое Context? Это системный класс или ваш собственный?

Comment: Из статического метода нет доступа к не статическим переменным и методам

Comment: @PavelMayorov `Context` - это альфа и омега разработки под андроид. Да, системный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандартные грабли. Многие по ним ходят (и я не исключение).

Самым правильным решением при работе с контекстом будет вообще отказаться от его сохранения. Если прямо вообще без этого не обойтись, то, как правильно заметили в комментариях, используйте `ApplicationContext`.

Дело в том, что контекст (кроме `ApplicationContext`) пересоздается при каждом пересоздании активити/фрагмента и полагаться на когда либо сохраненный в статике контекст равноситьно игре в русскую рулетку. Тут надо либо быть готовым к постоянным, как бы ниоткуда, возникающим исключениям, либо ОЧЕНЬ тщательно следить за его актуальностью.

Гораздо проще (и гугл сам так рекомендует и делает) и безопаснее передавать контекст параметром в конструктор или метод. Посмотрите на любой стандартный UI класс - у него всегда первым параметром идет `Context context`.

Да, это делает код менее "красивым", но зато на порядок более безопасным.

**UPD** ну и про утечку. Да, конечно она будет. Активность пересоздалась, контекст ее тоже пересоздался, а старый объект остался в памяти, поскольку ссылка на него лежит где-то в в статическом поле `Utility` класса.

Answer (score 1):

Не зря студия ругается. Сохранение контекста в статическую переменную обязательно приведёт к его утечке (если только это не `ApplicationContext`).

Чтобы не использовать статику, вы можете сделать инициализацию через конструктор, примерно так:

```
public class SomeSDK {
    private Context context;

    public SomeSDK(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

Comment: Мне надо как в VkSDK. `VkSDK.initialize(this)`

Comment: @Flippy Ну тогда смотрите как [это сделано там](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-android-sdk/blob/master/vksdk_library/src/main/java/com/vk/sdk/VKSdk.java#L164), раз вам нужно также. Там используется `ApplicationContext`.

Comment: А `статический ApplicationContext` не делает утечку памяти?

Comment: @Flippy, Нет. `ApplicationContext` создается при запуске приложения и существует до его завершения.